# How to find MongoDB index statistics

Tags: index, mongodb

Is there any way we can figure out what all indexes are cached into RAM ? I want to know page related stats for individual indexes (# of hits and miss )

Answer (score 9):

You can get overall (instance wide) hit info from the [`db.serverStatus()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/) command, and in particular:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/#serverStatus.indexCounters.hits
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/#serverStatus.indexCounters.misses

These numbers are totals seen for the lifetime of the process, so if you want to get a rate or see the trend over time, then you will need to record them periodically and diff the values accordingly.  Thankfully, if you install [MMS Monitoring](https://mms.mongodb.com), it will do that for you and graph the results.

However, there are currently no per-index statistics available.  The relevant feature request can be found here for tracking and voting purposes:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2227

**Update: January 2016**

The stats referenced above have been removed from the output of the server status command, so are no longer available.  However, the referenced feature request is now complete and is available in version 3.2 in the form of the [`$indexStats`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexStats/#pipe._S_indexStats) aggregation operator (the linked docs also contain sample output). For completeness, here's an example I put together:

Prior to any queries I have just 2 indexes, the default `_id` and `indexme`, both with 0 ops:

```
> db.foo.aggregate( [ { $indexStats: { } } ] ).pretty()
{
    "name" : "indexme_1",
    "key" : {
        "indexme" : 1
    },
    "host" : "localhost:27017",
    "accesses" : {
        "ops" : NumberLong(0),
        "since" : ISODate("2016-01-12T19:03:01.358Z")
    }
}
{
    "name" : "_id_",
    "key" : {
        "_id" : 1
    },
    "host" : "localhost:27017",
    "accesses" : {
        "ops" : NumberLong(0),
        "since" : ISODate("2016-01-12T18:59:24.292Z")
    }
}
```

Then run a couple of finds to bump the ops on `indexme` and check again:

```
> db.timecheck.find({indexme: 33})
> db.timecheck.find({indexme: 55})

> db.timecheck.aggregate( [ { $indexStats: { } } ] ).pretty()
{
    "name" : "indexme_1",
    "key" : {
        "indexme" : 1
    },
    "host" : "localhost:27017",
    "accesses" : {
        "ops" : NumberLong(2),
        "since" : ISODate("2016-01-12T19:03:01.358Z")
    }
}
{
    "name" : "_id_",
    "key" : {
        "_id" : 1
    },
    "host" : "localhost:27017",
    "accesses" : {
        "ops" : NumberLong(0),
        "since" : ISODate("2016-01-12T18:59:24.292Z")
    }
}
```

Comment: from the docs: "Changed in version 3.0: The server status output no longer includes the workingSet, indexCounters, and recordStats sections." Any other ideas?